# Android error in using curl as NDK?

Tags: android

I have following source code download from the link:
https://github.com/fuhu/curl-android
Now when I am running this code  i am getting the following error

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity    
  ComponentInfo{me.cutemay.demo/me.cutemay.demo.Demo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  me.cutemay.demo.Demo
```

Please help me in  to solve the error?

Comment: right click on project than go to android tools than fix project properties

Comment: its giving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what's happening:

> ComponentInfo{me.cutemay.demo/me.cutemay.demo.Demo}:
>   java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException**: me.cutemay.demo.Demo

It seems that the class Demo doesn't exist in the me.cutemay.demo package. Check your `AndroidManifest` and fix the name of the `activity`:

```
<activity
    android:name="package.name.here.Demo"
```

And make sure the Demo class is in that package. I think this should fix your problem.